# How to mount dynamically created Angular component?

Tags: angular

I have a function that creates Angular component. Let's assume the parent component doesn't use Angular so we can't pass in data with `[input]="input"`.

```js
(text) => {
  @Component({
    selector: 'container',
    template:'<div>{{text}}</div>'
  })
  class Component {}
}
```

How can we add this component to the declarations and bootstrap in the root module?

Imagine we have a React app that has five places to render this component. Do we have to call `bootstrapModule` five times?

Also, I can't use TypeScript in this case.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: TypeScript is not allowed